# Expand 2*2 matrix by inserting neighbor elements average

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, expand

I want to write a function that converts the matrix `x=[a b; c d]`
into another matrix:

```
y = [  a        (a+b)/2       b   ; 
     (a+c)/2  (a+b+c+d)/4   (b+d)/2 ; 
       c        (c+d)/2       d    ]
```

Comment: You mean resize with bilinear interpolation?

Comment: you  meant to write  `(a+b)/2` ,   `(a+c)/2` ,  etc. right? *Brackets are important*

Comment: yes,thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2D convolution to compute the sum of neighboring elements (the numerator of each element) and then use 2D convolution with a matrix of 1's to determine the denominator (the number of neighbors).

```
x = [1, 2; 3, 4];

numerator = conv2(x, ones(2));

%    1    3    2
%    4   10    6
%    3    7    4

denominator = conv2(ones(size(x)), ones(2));

%   1   2   1
%   2   4   2
%   1   2   1

result = numerator ./ denominator;

%   1.0000   1.5000   2.0000
%   2.0000   2.5000   3.0000
%   3.0000   3.5000   4.0000
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
result = conv2(x, ones(2)) ./ conv2(ones(size(x)), ones(2));
```

This is also the same as [bi-linear interpolation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/interpolation-methods.html#f13687) so you could also do the following:

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:0.5:size(x, 2), 1:0.5:size(x, 1));
result = interp2(x, xx, yy, 'linear');
```

Both of these methods have the added benefit of working for any size of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`mean`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) function as follows:

```
y = [x(:,1)  mean(x,2)   x(:,2)];
y = [y(1,:); mean(y,1);  y(2,:)];
```